# Media query to move heading to right of image

Tags: html, css

I have a site that needs the placement of an `h3` moved depending on the screen size.

The html is currently a table like this:

```
<table><tr><td><img src="someimage"></td><td><h3>Heading</h3></td></tr></table>
```

On smaller screens, I would want the h3 to appear above the image, with the image full width, so I start with:

```
<div class="heading-image">
<h3>Heading</h3>
<img="someimage">
</div>
```

That just works, but on larger screens I want the h3 to drop to the right of the image, which would be at 50% of the screen:

```
.heading-image img { max-width: 50% };
.heading-image h3 { max-width: 50%; float:right };
```

Now the h3 drops next to the image on the right hand side.  But then it comes to the age old problem of **vertically** centering multi-line text inside a div, where the height of the div is unknown (dependent on the size of the image and the current screen width), and the length of the text is unknown (these are entered into a CMS).

I have tried a variety of approaches found on the internet, but I am just not getting my head around it.  I tried making both the `img` and `h3` a `table-cell` to get me back to my original approach but I can't get the alignment to work.

[image]

Comment: DO you want vertical or horizontal center alignment?

Comment: @Anup Sorry guys, I left out the crucial word: vertical.

Comment: @Paul : you want to change the layout depending on the screen width....this sure sounds like `media-query` thing...

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes, I will create the media-query once I figure out (with help) how to get the layout to work.

Comment: @Paul : mmmmm....my englisg is poor....u want help in defining the layout?? :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes, specifically, I need help with the HTML+CSS so that the h3 appears above the img on small screens, and vertically centered to the right of the image on large screens. I'll add an image.

Comment: @Paul : ok...so lets start with you giving me a jsfiddle and then we are good to go fella :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45606/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-paul)

Comment: Aree yaarrr.... plz show the CSS

Comment: @Deekey The CSS is there in the post - did I miss something?

Comment: if you can show your Demo in jsfiddle, that would be more better

Comment: @Paul : updated my answer..please check

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code. Just change the size you want to collapse in the @media-query.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hv6x3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="heading-image">
    <h3>Headline text goes here...</h3>
    <img src="http://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading-image img { 
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
.heading-image h3 { 
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 50%; 
    text-align: left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .heading-image {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .heading-image img { 
        float: none;
        max-width: 100% 
    }
    .heading-image h3 { 
        float: none;
        max-width: 50%; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe - I think my original question didn't mention the "vertical aligned" part, which was silly, as this was the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

for vertical-align....use `display:table-cell`

make sure the parent div is set as `display:table`

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kZnqX/5/)

```
 html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 600px) {
    .heading-image {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center;
        display: table;
    }
    .heading-image .img {
        float:left;
        height:100%;
    }
    .heading-image .h3 {
        float:right;
        display: table;
        height:100%;

    }
    .heading-image .h3 h3 {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    .heading-image {
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align:center
    }
    .heading-image .img {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .heading-image .img img {
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
    }
    .heading-image .h3 {
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
}
```